# How to do HTML Template with multi color theme settings?

Tags: html, css, settings

I'm going to do multi color theme HTML Template. [image] How to do structure the CSS file. when change the color in one place it should be change in whole template. Please tell me it is possible or not. If it is possible please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to consider Learning SASS or LESS. I usually use SASS and just define some colors I can user throughout the whole app without having to copy the Hexidecimal values every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have choose sass or less. [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) with saturation.

**Supported Properties**

backgroundColor, borderBottomColor, borderLeftColor, borderRightColor, borderTopColor, color, columnRuleColor, outlineColor, textDecorationColor, textEmphasisColor